# Get City and Country Dropdown list Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, dropdown

I am trying to create a dependent dropdown list of countries and cities, based on the country selected I want to have another drop-down of cities in that country. In my Django model without creating models for country and city.

Here is my code:

```
models.py

from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from partial_date import PartialDateField

class School(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    school_country = CountryField()
    school_city = ??
    school_population = models.IntegerField()
    school_description = models.TextField(max_length = 300)
    year_build = PartialDateField()
    total_branches = models.IntegerField()
    school_fees = models.IntegerField()
    school_images = models.FileField(default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_name
```

I was able to get countries using django-countries `school_country = CountryField()` but I have no idea how to do the same for cities. I looked at django-cities but I didn't understand  how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Django Field Choices. According to documentation Field Choices are a sequence consisting itself of iterables of exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) …]) to use as choices for some field

```
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from partial_date import PartialDateField

SCHOOL_CITIES_CHOICES = (
    ("Newyork", "Newyork"),
    ("Dubai", "Dubai"),
    ("Arusha", "Arusha"),
    ("Nairobi", "Nairobi"),
    ("West papua", "West Papua"),
    )


class School(models.Model):

    school_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    school_country = CountryField()
    school_city =  models.CharField(
        max_length = 20,
        choices = SCHOOL_CITIES_CHOICES,
        default = '1'
        )
    school_population = models.IntegerField()
    school_description = models.TextField(max_length = 300)
    year_build = PartialDateField()
    total_branches = models.IntegerField()
    school_fees = models.IntegerField()
    school_images = models.FileField(default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_name
```

Comment: How will `school_city` be dependent on `school_country`?

Comment: should be two different model

Answer (score 0):

This is a Python's question, not a Django related thing.

You just need a structure that answer's on your question. It could be a simple dictionary like this:

```
{
   "USA": ["New York", "..."],
   "Canada": ["Ottawa", ".."]
}
```

and you can store it in the separated file in the project.

So you can use `.keys()` for countries list that you are supporting and you can use a specific country as a key to get cities' list.

If you need to show this scructure in the front-end, you can do it with 2 different ways:

1. Send all these stuff to the front-end and parse these things on the front end side *or*
2. Make an API endpoint and answer with specific cities' list when user selected a country.